# 5v/12vdc inputs and only one of those as outputs using PIC18fxxxx

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, pic, switches, integrated-circuit

Hey all I am trying to find an **IC** that can accommodate having 2 inputs but only one output depending on what I send via a **PIC18fxxxx** micro controller. This sounds like it would be a **DPST** but I can't really find anything like that I can control from a PIC to choose what output needs to be on.

The 5vdc and 12vdc will be to power a PC FAN. The 5 and 12vdc will be coming from the PC PSU.

```
A 12vdc fan is around 0.25A ~4W
A 5vdc fan is around 0.18A ~2W
```

So something like so:

```
                |------|
---5vdc-in----->|  IC  |
---12vdc-in---->|  ?   |-----5 or 12vdc-out-->
---PIC pin-in-->|      |
                |------|
```

Or better visually is this:

[image]

The PIC pin would control the IC to let it know which voltage to output.

Does anyone know if this type of IC exists? I'll need to be able to do 10 outputs all together.

Comment: Instead of describing what you think you need, can you describe what you're trying to accomplish?  I think you just need an open collector driver, where you change the open collector voltage.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I figured that the drawing I did pretty much sums up what I am needing the IC to do. 2 inputs and one output . The output is controlled by the PIC and determines which input to use for the output.

Comment: How much current?  A relay?

Comment: @MD look at my updated OP.

Comment: ...Why the down votes....???

Comment: Much clearer after the edit.  It's not even clear to me that you need an IC.  You're in the middle of an XY problem, but the edit clears it up enough for someone to answer.  FWIW, an "IC" probably wouldn't source enough current to drive a fan. That's why you need to tell people what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: What's a 'PC FAN'? How much current does it draw at 12V, 5V?

Comment: @BruceAbbott updated my OP to have that info.

Comment: A fan that draws that draws 0.18A at 5V, and 0.25A at 12V? Or is it to power _either_ a 5V fan _or_ a 12V fan (why)?

Comment: @BruceAbbott to **power either a 5 or 12vdc fan.**

Comment: Then why have a switch at all? You wouldn't want to switch the wrong voltage to the fan, so just connect it directly to the voltage that it needs.

Comment: @BruceAbbott It will be controlled by software which will warn the user before it sets it to 12vdc.

Answer (score 1):

Look for an SPDT (or 1 Form C) relay.  If you want it to be an IC, you could look at a solid state relay.  Or, you could build something like this with complementary power switches (i.e., one is active high and the other active low).  Depending upon how much current you intend to put through it, you might also use an analog switch/mux.

Comment: my resent OP update may be what you might be talking about here?